# Terraform "vpc" module "private_subnets" value after "apply"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have created a vpc using module "vpc" , Please clarify how the variable private_subnets or public_subnets be assigned with Subnet ID after "apply" BUT my question is, in "resource" block these variables are assigned CIDR blocks.

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  enable_vpn_gateway = true

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing module input variables, and output values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module contains multiple resources and when you take a look at the code of the [terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc) module you will see that the private_subnets and public_subnets are used to create `aws_subnet` resources:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = local.create_vpc && length(var.private_subnets) > 0 ? length(var.private_subnets) : 0

  vpc_id                          = local.vpc_id
  cidr_block                      = var.private_subnets[count.index]
}
```

([main.tf L. 384](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/main.tf#L384))

Comment: Thank you @Ausgefuchster for looking into this, still I have question how Subnet id subnet-xxxxxxe of 3 occurences was assigned to private_subnets Variable but we have given input as CIDR block  ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]

Comment: The module has the output `private_subnets` https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/outputs.tf#L71 . And there you can see that it's a list of the ids. There is also an output called `private_subnets_cidr_blocks`

Comment: Thank you very much @Ausgefuchster it makes sense now, same variable is used as input to accepts CIDR blocks but in "output" it's given with ID

Comment: I am glad I could help. There is also no need to thank me in the comments as comments are used to ask for clarifications . A better way to express gratitude is to accept the answer if it helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: accepted your answer.